# Check if index in table exist

Tags: indexing, lua, lua-table

I have problem; I must check in my program one field in table.

```
if(launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom.test_field ~= nil)then...
```

and when this index exist everything is ok, but when it isn't exist, I get an error :

```
Attempt to index field 'notification' (a nil value).
```

And it is understandable. How check if that index exist?

Comment: Is `notifiaction` a typo of `notification`?

Comment: @EtanReisner, that seems to be the point.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, i corrected it.

Comment: Updated my answer according to your typo fix (fixed the typo as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
if (launchArgs and launchArgs.androidIntent and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras 
    and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom
    and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom.test_field) then
-- do you stuff
end
```

This code will check if each table is set.

If you're sure launch args.androidIntent.extras is always set you can just do this

```
if(launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom and launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom.test_field)then
    -- do your stuff
end
```

**OR Just use this function, that I posted in some other answer (helps here too )**

```
function IndexScan(input,value,case,_type)
    if (input and type(input) == 'table') then
        if (_type) then
            if (type(value) == _type and value == input) then
                return true;
            end
        else
            if (type(value) == 'table' and value == input) then
                return true;
            end
        end
        for key,object in pairs(input) do
            if (case and type(input)=='string' and type(key)=='string') then
                if (_type) then
                    if (value:lower() == key:lower() and type(object)==_type) then
                        return true;
                    elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                        return IndexScan(object,value,case,_type)
                    end
                else
                    if (value:lower() == key:lower()) then
                        return true;
                    elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                        return IndexScan(object,value,case,_type)
                    end
                end
            else
                if (_type) then
                    if (key == value and type(object)==_type) then
                        return true
                    elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                        return IndexScan(object,value,case,_type)
                    end
                else
                    if (key == value) then
                        return true
                    elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                        return IndexScan(object,value,case,_type)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return false;
end
-- IndexScan(@param table(table), @param index(string), @param case-sensitive(true/false), @param type (index type, string/boolean/number/table ...))
-- checks if these two indexes were set any where in the launchArgs table and checks their type
if (IndexScan(launchArgs,"notification",false,"table") and IndexScan(launchArgs,"test_field",false,"string")) then
    -- do your stuff
end
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed some mistake in the function.

**EDIT:**
Updated the script after the author fixed the Notification typo.

Comment: Shorter alternative: `local T = {}; if (((((launchArgs or T).androidIntent or T).extras or T).notification or T).custom or T).test_field then end`

Comment: @siffiejoe that method takes a while, and not really safe (unless T is always being set before this checking that field).
But again, my first 2 options and your options, still take some time.
The function is ideal for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
function setglobal(name,value)
    local t=_ENV
    local f="_G"
    for x in name:gmatch("[^.]+") do
        if t[f]==nil then t[f]={} end
        t=t[f]
        f=x
    end
    t[f]=value
end

function getglobal(name)
    local t=_ENV
    for x in name:gmatch("[^.]+") do
        t=t[x]
        if t==nil then return nil,x end
    end
    return t
end

setglobal("launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom.test_field",2014)
print(getglobal("launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notification.custom.test_field"))
print(getglobal("launchArgs.androidIntent.extras.notifiaction.custom.test_field"))
```

This assumes that the top-level variable is a global variable. Adapt as needed.

Comment: This won't work on LUA < 5.2,For those who wish to use it, use `getfenv(0)` instead of `_ENV`.

Comment: @user812331, Lua 5.2 has been out for 3 years now... But thanks for the 5.1 backport.

Comment: There is no need to create globals at all to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
local function try(root, query)
  local ids, len = {}, 0
  for id in query:gmatch("%w+") do
    len = len + 1
    ids[len]= id
  end

  local node = root
  for i=1,len do
    if type(node) ~= 'table' then return nil end
    node = node[ids[i]]
  end

  return node
end
```

Usage:

```
local tbl = { a = { b = { c = { d = 1 } } } }

print(try(tbl, 'a.b.c.d')) -- prints 1
print(try(tbl, 'a.b.c.x')) -- prints nil
print(try(tbl, 'a.x.c.d')) -- prints nil
```